# Access 2003 - Query can't get combo box value off of subform

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to use a combo box's value from a subform to use as the criteria for a query. It I use the form as a stand alone form, with this in the criteria field, it works fine:

Forms!FormStats!ControlName

I then try to run it as a subform on a main form with this code, and it doesn't work:

Forms!MasterForm!FormStats.Form!ControlName

I've been trying all day to figure this out with no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: What else happens when it doesn't work?  Does Access display an error message?

Comment: It says "Enter Parameter Value" and displays Forms!MasterForm!FormStats.Form!ControlName. It is as if it doesn't exist.

Comment: When `FormStats` is contained in the subform control of another form, use the name of the control which contains `FormStats`.  My hunch is the subform control is named something else (perhaps something like `Child0`) ... but not `FormStats`. Find that name and use it here in place of `SubformControlName` -> `Forms!MasterForm!SubformControlName!ControlName`

Comment: @HansUp So here is what I think is my hierarchy: I have a MainForm > TabCtl5 (a set of tabs on the main form) > StatsPage (the name of the tab on which I dumped my subform) > FormStats (my subform) > My combo box where I'm trying to get the parameter. What would my chain look like in this case?

Comment: FYI, I have also added a text field on my form displaying my query and set its control source to the same criteria as my query is using just to see if I am passing the value. When I use Form!MasterForm!TabCtl5!ControlName, I get #Error in the text field and nothing in my query. When I try any other iteration, I get #Name? in the text box. So I think what you've suggested above is closest to correct, but why the error still?

Comment: I asked you about the name of the subform control.  Were you unable to find it, or is the subform control actually named `FormStats`?

Comment: So I feel less than intelligent right now. I changed the name of the subform on my forms list to FormStats, but in the main form I had not updated the subform control name. I swear I'd looked at that, but today I found it as the old name. Updating it to FormStats fixed my error, and it works just like you showed in your first response. Thank you for the help!